# '404 Not Found' error while running Python as a service

Tags: python, windows, flask, service

I have developed a HTML webpage for which data is fed by Python code served via Flask. I am trying to run this flask code as a service in Windows using the win32service package. (Coded it on Python3.6) 
When I run the flask code on cmd via the command : python tryflask.py debug, it shows the page running on the IP with port number, etc. (Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000). But nothing is displayed on the webpage. I get the error: 404 Not Found.
Where am I going wrong? Also, I figured that it is not entering the "def slides()" function in the flask code.

Below is the flask program.

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
from extract import *
import sys
from flask import request
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/slideshow')
def slides():
   print ("Hello")          //Not getting printed
   ext_obj=extract_news()
   hntop = ext_obj.hntop()
   br=ext_obj.breaking()

   ext_tweet= ext_obj.extract_tweet()
   tweet1=ext_obj.tweet1()
   tweet2=ext_obj.tweet2()
   return render_template('exampleslide.html', hntop=hntop, br=br, tweet1=tweet1, tweet2=tweet2, )

@app.route('/newspage', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def loadhome():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      ext_obj=extract_news()
      hn=ext_obj.hacker_news()
      tp=ext_obj.hacker_news()
      return render_template('home.html',tp=tp,hn=hn)

def start_flask():
    print("Starting flask")      //Printing
    app.run('0.0.0.0',port=5000)

class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "newsslides"
    _svc_display_name_ = "newsslides"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(6000)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        print ("Starting service")     //Printing
        start_flask()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you go to `http://0.0.0.0:5000/slideshow`

Comment: @Ken: I get the following error:

Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: What about `http://127.0.0.1:5000/slideshow`

Comment: Is it working when you run it NOT as Windows Service ? Did you open port 5555 in your firewall ?

Comment: @Ken: Still not working. Returns the same error.

Comment: @Maurice: Yup, it works perfectly fine when I run it NOT as a windows service. And the port is open. Still the same error.

Comment: Is the service actually running after you start it, or is it starting and insta-stopping? Try putting `while self.run == True: time.sleep(30)` in the start_flask method.

Comment: @KenSyme: The service is running after I start it. 
And when I add the line of code which you suggested, I get the following error when I run flask code in debug mode-

'Error 0xC0000003 - The instance's SvcRun() method failed

<Error getting traceback - traceback.print_exception() failed

(null): (null)'

Comment: Try `while True: time.sleep(30)`. It's 2 lines, with the `time.sleep(30)` on a new line and idented (sorry can't do multiline code in a comment). Might need to `import time`. Should appear after app.run. I have never done a windows service in python before, but when I have done them previously they usually have an infinite loop to stop them exiting.

Comment: @KenSyme : I tried the code snippet you suggested. I get this new error: 

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: @KenSyme : Your suggestion WORKED! The "Internal Server Error" was due to a tiny bug in my code, but your code snippet to stop it from exiting did the magic! Thanks a ton for your time and effort!

Comment: @Pooja you're welcome, I have added as an answer if you could accept/upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running windows services, the DoRun function can never return otherwise the service will essentially stop. Add this to the bottom of your start_flask method:

```
while True: 
    time.sleep(30)
```